# Mostrar datos con laravel

Tags: php, laravel

estoy tratando de mostrar una campo de mi base de datos con laravel, el problema con el que me encuentro es el siguiente.

Al mostrarlo en la web se ve así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo muestro de esta manera

```php
{{ $server->description}}
```

Pero si lo muestro así se ve de manera correcta

```php
<?= $server['description'] ?>
```

Alguna idea de como mostrarlo usando alguna propiedad de laravel? o debo de usar si o si la segunda forma

Comment: @BetaM ya  lo he modificado.

Comment: Por defecto, las declaraciones Blade `{{ }}` se envían automáticamente a través de la función `htmlspecialchars` de PHP para evitar ataques XSS.  Si no desea que se escapen sus datos, puede usar la siguiente sintaxis: `{!!  $variable !!}`.

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ con eso ya funciona pero salen corchetes al principio y al final

Comment: ¿Estás poniendo dos corchetes? Nota que es un corchete y dos signos de esclamación. En vez de `{{ }}` es `{!! !!}`

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ solucionado, gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución es poner lo siguiente

```php
{!! $server->description !!}
```

Sería quitar un corchete a cada lado y poner los símbolos de exclamación

Comment: Te paso el enlace a la documentación dónde se menciona eso para que lo agregues como referencia en la respuesta, Blade Templates [Displaying Data](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#displaying-data), ahí podrás ver la explicación detallada. Y por favor agrega la nota (traducida) que dice "Be very careful when echoing content that is supplied by users of your application. Always use the escaped, double curly brace syntax to prevent XSS attacks when displaying user supplied data." pues es importante.

Comment: Perfecto y muchas gracias